# Install amphp / thread on a Debian Wheezy 64 bits

Tags: php, multi-threading

I'm trying to install a multi-thread PHP system on one of my server. After a few readings, the simplest solution seems to use Pthreads with an [`amphp\thread`](https://github.com/amphp/thread) implementation.

http://www.mullie.eu/parallel-processing-multi-tasking-php/

So, If I'm right the steps were this :

- Install PHP 5.5+ with ZTS and Pthreads (http://eddmann.com/posts/compiling-php-5-5-with-zts-and-pthreads-support/)
- Then install amphp which require php-uv or libevent

When I'm trying to install [`php-uv`](https://github.com/chobie/php-uv), I get an error on the step:

```
make -C libuv CFLAGS=-fPIC
```

Because the libuv directory is not on the git so I think I'm missing something...

Never the less, I also installed php libevent which can do the trick if I don't misunderstand the `amphp` README.

- How can I test that this kind of library are well installed? I don't get any error, but who knows?**
- Also, I install `amphp` with `composer` as it's described in the docs. But again, how can I test that the installation went well?

Then, if I assume everything went well, I can now install `amphp/thead`.
Same question with the composer, how can I be sure that it's OK?

Then, I'm supposed to be ready so I create a `test.php` file with the example code in the `amphp/thread` and of course... I get an error which said that `Amp\Thread\Dispatcher` class is not found. Of course I'm running it in CLI.

So to sum up, I only get error when installing `php-uv` which doesn't seem to be absolutely required to run the class. So I'm pretty sure I'm missing something somewhere but don't know what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `uv` nor `libevent`, they don't play together with `pthreads`.

There's now a stable release for [`amphp/amp`](https://github.com/amphp/amp/releases/tag/v1.0.0), but [`amphp/thread`](https://github.com/amphp/thread) is still not stable, it's not even updated to the stable release of `amp` yet.

If you don't get an error during installation, everything went well. That's typical for Linux, if there's no message, everything usually worked well.

To get some `test.php` up and running with [`composer`](http://getcomposer.org), you have to include the autoloader:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

// your code here...
```

> You can play with `amphp/thread`, but be warned, the API may change at any time without any notice.